# How do I mantain the state of a page when refreshed?

Tags: c#, reactjs

There is a activekey (questionmanagement tab) which loads on refresh. I don't want it to happen like that. On refresh, It should load the current tab(or page) not the questionmanagement. How should I retain the state?

```
class ContentHome extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      activeKey: 'questionManagementTab',
      openModal: false
    }
    this.handleTabChange = this.handleTabChange.bind(this)
    this.leavePage = this.leavePage.bind(this)
    this.handleCloseModal = this.handleCloseModal.bind(this)
  }
```

Comment: You should use the same instance of the class instead of creating a new instance every time you call the class.

Comment: You need to set activeKey to the URL as a param. That way it will retain the current tab even after a page refresh

Answer (score 1):

When you are refreshing, the component unmounts and mount again, so It's completely normal to get the `questionManagementTab` from the initial state.

If you want to save the data like this on your component and prevent losing it during the refresh page, you can save the tab data on local storage or cookies before the component unmount, and then initial the state with the local storage or cookies data.